# How to manipulate data in an Excel Spreadsheet with Google Apps Script

Tags: excel, windows, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have stored a Excel spreadsheet in my Google Drive. I am able to open it with `Excel 2003 and with Google sheets. The operating system is Windows 10.

My goal is to update the spreadsheet with data from a `Google Form` and use the spreadsheet as an input to a windows program.

I have tried to open the spreadsheet with methods `openById(id)` and `openByUrl(url)` without any success.

Is there any way I can manipulate the data in this spreadsheet with Google Apps Script?

Comment: I think that to provide your current script will help users think of the issue and solution. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: You could programmatically: upload to drive>convert to  Google sheets> modify it> export back to excel. Alternatively, if excel provides any sort of *public https* api to access/modify your file, then it's possible to access excel from apps script.

Comment: Thete is no script to provide.  I just tried to open the Excel file stored in my Google Drive with the two candidate methods, "openById(id)" and "openByUrl(url)", before start coding.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike for the advice. My question was solved with the help of [link](https://ctrlq.org/code/20124-convert-google-spreadsheet-to-excel) and [link](https://ctrlq.org/code/20500-convert-microsoft-excel-xlsx-to-google-spreadsheet) .